# How can we create request, response cycle with JSP pages?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, xhtml, facelets

While developing JSP pages, we can run a Java code in server side, while JSP page is active in the client side... 
How to create request and response cycle between Java Code(at the server side) and JSP page(at the client side)... 
What is the difference between JSP and JSF technology for this kind of dynamic web pages?
And which one is better JSF or JSP?

Comment: JSP code executed on server side, not client

Comment: Yes, but JSP code generates web page for the client side, How to create request, response cycle between client side page and server side code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `RequestDispatcher  Method`
In Server side  create test.java you  can write

```
ServletContext context= getServletContext();
RequestDispatcher rd= context.getRequestDispatcher("/LoggedIn");
rd.forward(request, response);// used to forward data
```

if you want to include data use

```
rd.include(request,response);// used to include data
```

Answer (score 0):

The common way to send information from java code to JSP is to set appropriate attributes of `HttpServletRequest` object.  But you can't access JSP variables from java code because there is no sense in it. So it's "unidirectional communication", and when JSP page was sent to client only new HTTP request can help you.

Schematic HTTP request processing:

`client -> servlet container -> servlet -> JSP -> HTML -> client`

Comment: Can we use Servlet to create request, response cycle with JSP pages ?

Comment: @CMDody no, servlet just provide required information for JSP processing. Then JSP processor create HTML from JSP and send it to client. Take a look at `ajax` approach, it allows you to send new HTTP requests from client side without html page refresh.